# MPlus Cross-Level-Interaction

Tags: mplus

I would like to run a Cross-Level Interaction in `MPlus` with a Level-2 Moderator and fixed slopes. I do not center the level 1 predictor because I use latent aggregation.

Does anyone know of any good code on Cross-Level Interaction with only fixed slopes?

Comment: ¿Have you happened to review 
EXAMPLE 9.24:  REGRESSION FOR A CONTINUOUS DEPENDENT VARIABLE USING CROSS-CLASSIFIED DATA from the Mplus user guide?  I believe this might be the scenario you are referencing